# How to fetch logs continuously from logcat programmatically?

Tags: android, adb

I am fetching android logs using logcat with following piece of program:

```
Process process=runtime.exec("logcat"); 
BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Pictures/logs.txt");
String line; while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
        fos.write(line.getBytes()); 
}
```

But the problem is it will fetch all logs at once and will write to the file.

However, I want to keep polling logcat for new logs and want to write the log to the file whenever there is a new log available.

Can you please suggest a way to do this ?

Comment: HI are you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

To fetch logcat

```
try {
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat");
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

  StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
  String line = "";
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    log.append(line);
  }
  TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  tv.setText(log.toString());
  } 
catch (IOException e) {}
```

make sure

- you run this on a separate thread
- apply filters to the log , as the output can be exhaustive

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing but the problem is it will get logs available at that moment. How do I get new logs ?

Comment: you would have to run it in a service and execute it periodically to get the latest output

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good approach. Just imagine if period is not short enough there will be few logs which won't be available in the logcat buffer and system will miss it.

Comment: when you run the logcat command it dumps till that timestamp. So , to get the new logcat output you have to execute logcat again.

Comment: you can output logcat displaying time , adb logcat -d -v time . You can use the timestamp value , to filter logcat after a particular point of time

Comment: Ahh. That sounds like a good idea. Let me think if it solves my purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79847/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-r7v).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `fos.flush();` into your while cycle.

Your cycle could appear like this:

```
while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
    fos.write(line.getBytes());
    fos.flush();
}
```

It is untested solution, so let me know if it would not work.